# Allow communities user to see multiple Accounts

Tags: community, account, sharing, contact, sharing-sets

I have multiple Accounts associated with a single Contact in Salesforce, and I want to see if I can give a User access to these multiple accounts in communities.

For now, I can only see the directly associated Account in communities. If I set Accounts to public read/write OWD, I can see all of them in communities so I'm guessing there could be a way to show them sharing rules or sharing sets.

Is there a way to show ALL related accounts (not just the directly related accounts) based on the User's Contact?

Comment: What’s the criteria that define related accounts?

Comment: Can you share the detailed solution on how you achieved, please?  followed the document but got stuck somewhere

Comment: @dinesh I really don't remember and I can't go look it up because I'm no longer part of that project. Are you able to at least see the one directly related account in communities? I remember one of my earlier problems was that we had a customer community license and not the customer community plus license which supports more sharing options and we didn't have the issue with customer community plus licenses. Also, this was before Summer '18 so sfdc's answer could be of help to you.

Comment: Yeah okay, I got it using SFDC's answer, thank you. target object - Account - Contact.RelatedAccount - Id, Yes Initially I could only see only directly related accounts and Now after sharing sets could non-Related account too. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, sharing sets now support the Contacts with Multiple Accounts feature. Let’s say you create a community or portal user from a contact that is associated with multiple accounts. You can then create a sharing set that grants access to all records with a lookup to any account that contact is related to.
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_networks_sharing_sets_cma_support.htm